# Process JSON to Fasta, convert Python code to Groovy

Tags: python, json, groovy, fasta, jsonslurper

I have a config file that looks like this:

```
{
    "codes": {
        "0004F--0004R": {
            "Forward code Name": "0004F",
            "Forward code Info": "xxxyyy4",
            "Rev code Name": "0004R",
            "Rev code Info": "xxxyyy3"
        },
        "0014F--0014R": {
            "Forward code Name": "0014F",
            "Forward code Info": "xxxyyy1",
            "Rev Barcode Name": "0014R",
            "Rev Barcode Info": "xxxyyy2"

        }
    }
}
```

I need to process this json so that I get an output "fasta" file that looks like this:

```
>0004F
xxxyyy4
>0004R
xxxyyy3
>0014F
xxxyyy1
>0014R
xxxyyy2
```

I am essentially a python programmer, so in python my code looks like this:

```
with open('codes.fasta', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in json_object.get('codes', {}).items():
        fname, revname = k.split('--')
        print(f'>{fname}\n{v["Forward code Info"]}', file=f)
        print(f'>{revname}\n{v["Rev code Info"]}', file=f)
```

I need to write a similar function in Groovy.

In pseudo code:
 1. Give config.json
 2. Groovy reads the JSON
 3. Parses JSON accordingly
 4. Outputs a "fasta" file

Any Groovy coders out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonObject = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''{
    "codes": {
        "0004F--0004R": {
            "Forward code Name": "0004F",
            "Forward code Info": "xxxyyy4",
            "Rev code Name": "0004R",
            "Rev code Info": "xxxyyy3"
        },
        "0014F--0014R": {
            "Forward code Name": "0014F",
            "Forward code Info": "xxxyyy1",
            "Rev Barcode Name": "0014R",
            "Rev Barcode Info": "xxxyyy2"

        }
    }
}'''

new File('codes.fasta').withOutputStream { out ->
    jsonObject.codes.each { code -> 
        def (fname, revname) = code.key.split('--')
        out << ">$fname\n${code.value['Forward code Info']}\n"
        out << ">$revname\n${code.value['Rev Barcode Info']}\n"
    }
}
```

You can write Groovy in a very analogous way.

Instead of parsing using `parseText` you'll likely want to call `parse(new File(config.json)` or some other similar [API method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html#parse(java.io.File)).

Comment: To be closer to python possible to use `jsonObject.codes.each { k,v ->`

Comment: Thank you, sir. You are a lifesaver!